# What's the difference between //node and /descendant::node in xpath?

Tags: xpath

I use a lot of XPath when locating elements in web pages using Selenium, and have moved away from using node1//node2 towards using node1/descendant::node2 more recently. What's the difference between the two methods? Is one more efficient than the other?

Example XML snippet to demonstrate:

```
<div id="books">
  <table>
    <tr><td class="title">Lord of the Rings</td><td class="author">JRR Tolkein</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="title">The Hitch-Hikers Guide to the Galaxy</td><td class="author">Douglas Adams</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

So it'd be:

```
id('books')//td[@class='title']
```

or:

```
id('books')/descendant::td[@class='title']
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between // and /descendant in XPath selecting multiple children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918010/differences-between-and-descendant-in-xpath-selecting-multiple-children)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev

// is just an abbreviation for the descendant:: axis

**Edit**

To quote:

> //para is short for /descendant-or-self::node()/child::para

That is, it refers to all para which are a child of the context node or any node descended from the context node. As far as I can tell that translates into any descendant para of the context node.

Comment: I should have scoured the TR before asking. For others http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev is the relevant section. It would appear though that // is short for descendant-or-self so not exactly the same. Also, the reason I've stayed away from using // is that //node[1] is not the same as /descendant::node[1]

Comment: I've expanded on that point above. // is not descendant-or-self, it is descendant-or-self/child.... which looks an awful lot like descendant to me.

Comment: Please see Motty's answer, which highlights the actual important differences, i.e. `descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` is *not* the same as `descendant::para`. Can get you into trouble if you assume they are the same. For a more detailed answer see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918010/differences-between-and-descendant-in-xpath-selecting-multiple-children#33920245).

Answer (score 14):

There's a difference in the context group. `//para[1]` is short for
`/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para[1]`, which returns every para that is the first child of its parent.  `/descendant::para[1]` returns only the first para in the entire subtree.

Comment: Also (//para)[1] should also work but doesn't in Selenium 1 so you have to use /descendant::para[1]. Anyone know how the context group is applied differently between//node[1] and /descendant::node[1]?

Answer (score 8):

In your case

```
 id('books')//td[@class='title']
```

and:

```
 id('books')/descendant::td[@class='title']
```

return the same result.

But in fact, like it was already stated before, `id('books')//td[@class='title']` means `id('books')/descendant-or-self::node()/td[@class='title']` which is different from `id('books')/descendant::td[@class='title']` in concept.

See the following note:

> NOTE: The location path //para[1] does not mean the same as the location path /descendant::para[1]. The latter selects the first descendant para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are the first para children of their parents.

this note was taken from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev

Answer (score 2):

Other than terseness, I'm not aware of any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer is more of a functional correctness, but in case it helps anyone, I stumbled across a key difference today.

When selecting elements based on some property of a descendant (like attribute).  For example:

```
...
<foo id="ID1">
    <bar>
        <baz at2="c" />
    </bar>
</foo>
<foo2 id="ID2">
    <bar>
        <baz at2="d" />
    </bar>
</foo2>
...
```

To select the `id` attribute of all elements who have a descendant with an attribute `at2=c`:

This xpath will select foo and foo2:

```
//*[//*[@at2="c"]]/@id
```

while this xpath will only select foo:

```
//*[descendant::*[@at2="c"]]/@id
```