# UPDATE: Parse and clean SVG; keeping select attributes, deleting inner g elements

Tags: xml, regex, parsing, svg, batch-processing

I am trying to recreate a batch of (360 files) SVGs because they were given a `<clip
path>` tag that points to a `<rect>` tag inside of `<defs>` tags. It also created a `<polygon>` element with a fill attribute. I am trying to delete the `<clipPath>`, `<defs>` and `<polygon>` tags, but keep the `<rect>` tag and give it the polygon's fill attribute.

I tried to do this in regex, but it was too complicated and didn't seem like it could be done very well.

I tried to dabble with doing it in java with an xml parser class, but I could not figure out how to access the attributes (I tried using the `.getAttributes()` method, but it would not pull the attributes for the element).

Here is some of my sample code:

```
<defs>
    <rect id="SVGID_1_" y="0" width="1023.88" height="100.08"/>
</defs>
<clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
    <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  display="none" overflow="visible"/>
</clipPath>
<polygon clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#E81E25" points="-0.12,0 -0.12,100.08 1023.88,100.08 1023.88,0"/>
```

This is what it should be:

```
<rect fill="#E81E25" width="1023.88" height="100.08"/>
```

How can I  batch convert 360 files to be formatted like I want above with the `<rect>` tag?

Comment: do you have a file or just the HTML (SVG) page in browser?

Comment: @Thomas Here's an example [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5zc9v2d8i4kxdh/F-08.svg)

Comment: @halfbit here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5zc9v2d8i4kxdh/F-08.svg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT would be a perfect fit.  Does that what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <!-- Identity transform for all cases except the ones we want to delete -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- We do nothing for clipPaths and polygons -->
  <xsl:template match="svg:clipPath|svg:polygon"/>

  <!-- We only copy rects from defs -->
  <xsl:template match="svg:defs">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="svg:rect">
    <xsl:variable name="clipPathId" select="//svg:use[substring(@xlink:href,2) = current()/@id]/../@id"/>
    <rect>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="//svg:polygon[@clip-path=concat('url(#', $clipPathId, ')')]/@fill"/>
    </rect>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes you want to delete **all** `<clipPath>` and `<polygon>` elements as well as stripping all `<defs>` elements, only keeping `<rect>` elements that are found inside.

Use any XSLT processor you like (Saxon, Xalan, xsltproc, msxsl...).

Comment: That answer seems close, however, it is not copying the fill attribute from the `<polygon>` tag. I need to get the fill attribute from the `<polygon>` and put it in my `<rect>`

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't quite get that part.  I updated the answer. Does this work better?

Comment: I don't know much about XSLTs. What does "node()|@*" mean? Do you have any sites you can recommend to learn about XSLTs?

Comment: Thomas I owe you an apology. I didn't know what XSLT was and I was not confident in your solution. However, after two days of trying to figure it out I got it to do exactly what I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can [read about the identity transform (which has the `node()|@*` matching pattern) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT). As for learning XSLT: If you want to dedicate some time to it, I recommend getting a book. [Here are some suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51271/what-is-a-good-resource-for-learning-xsl) (both in book and online form). When working with XSLT, keep in mind it works sort-of-but-not-quite like a functional programming language and the control flow is determined by template matching.

Comment: What does "//" in //svg:polygon mean? @Thomas

Comment: `//` means "grab all polygon elements in the document" - if there's nothing preceding the `//`. In this case it's the same as the CSS selector `polygon`. If you'd have `/svg:svg/svg:g[1]//svg:polygon`, then this would find the first `<g>` element under the document element, and inside this element grab all polygon elements. Possibly also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537771/whats-the-difference-between-node-and-descendantnode-in-xpath).

Answer (score 0):

*preamble: since your files a generated by an other programm you can assume with little risk that all tags look the same, so you can try to ignore, that it is 'xml': with little risk. If your files are fom different sources (or different versions of that programm), my suggestion wont work or at least is more complex!*

What I would do is parse (each) file, split the data and reassamble it, this is only a hint and i try to dont use languge specific things:

The - lets call it - primary id you can use is: "id=SVGID_xxx_"

iterate ofer the file and regex:

```
<rect.*id="([^"]*).*width="([^"]*).*height="([^"]*)
           ^--R1            ^--R2          ^--R3
```

keep the data like (depends on your language)

```
rect_array[R1].width=R2     // or $rect_list[$R1]["w"]=R2; // php like
rect_array[R1].height=R3
```

then a 2nd iteration

```
<polygon.*?\(([^)]*).*?fill=.([^'"]*)
           ^--R1 (id again)   ^--color
```

and add it to your hash/array/map

```
rect_array[R1].fill=color     // or $rect_list[$R1]["f"]=color; // php like
```

last step is to iterate over your list/array and reassabmle it

```
for_all_in(rect_array).do    // foreach($rect_array as $rd) 
puts/echo rect="<rect ...    //   echo "<rect width='rd[w]' ...
```

HTH