# XQuery: // vs descendant-or-self::node()

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xquery, descendant-or-self

Recently I needed to evaluate an XQuery on the Node of an HTML document. Basically, I needed to select all elements with an href attribute from the first child of the body element. I've added a slight example to explain:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.be"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The desired extraction result is in this case obviously:

```
<a href="http://www.google.be"/>
```

My first idea was to use `//body/*[1]//*[@href]` because:

- `//body` matches the body element, wherever it is
- `/*[1]` matches the first child of the body element
- `//*[@href]` matches all descendants or self of the current element

I figured that would work but on the example provided, the XQuery gives no results.

However, I read up a bit and found the following (source: http://www.keller.com/xslt/8/):

```
Alternate notation for "//": descendant-or-self::node()
```

So I changed my XQuery to `//body/*[1]/descendant-or-self::node()[@href]` and this time, the results were correct.

My question: what is the difference between // and descendant-or-self::node()? What I found here ([What's the difference between //node and /descendant::node in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537771/whats-the-difference-between-node-and-descendantnode-in-xpath)) and here (http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes) says:

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For example, `//para` is
>   short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para`.

Which leads me to conclude that `//` and `/descendant-or-self::node()` are not interchangeable (probably because of the terminating `/` at the end?), but then can someone tell me if there is a shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()`?

Comment: `//` is shorthand for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` _including the leading and trailing slashes_, there is no shorthand notation for `descendant-or-self::node()` _without_ the slashes, you'd have to spell it out in full.

Comment: Thanks Ian, that was concise yet to the point. Long story short: there is no shorthand without the slashes.

Comment: @IanRoberts Moreover, one could stress that the '/' in /descendant-or-self::node() is referring to the very root node of the DOM; so the implementation starts looking at each and every node in the tree. This might be hard to grasp for a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first XPath expression (`//body/*[1]//*[@href]`) actually represents what you described in natrual language: `//body/*[1]` is the first child of the body element, and `//*[@href]` selects the first element (below) having an `@href` attribute.

In your example, there is no element below the anchor tag having such an attribute. Fore xample, this query would match

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.google.be"/>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The non-abbreviated version of this query is:

```
//body/*[1]/descendant-or-self::node()/*[@href]
```

Putting your second query in contrast, the problem should be easy to see:

```
//body/*[1]/descendant-or-self::node()[@href]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your description, it does not appear to match your example!

Given the input:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.be"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the requirements statement:

"all elements with an href attribute from the first child of the body element"

Your XPath formulation of:

```
//body/*[1]//*[@href]
```

matches your requirements statement. But, the expected output would be an empty sequence, exactly as you have found... and NOT the output you suggested:

```
<a href="http://www.google.be"/>
```

To get the suggested output, your XPath requirements statement would instead perhaps be:

"the first child of the body element with an href attribute", which would lead to the XPath:

```
//*[@href][parent::body][1]
```

From your requirements statement and the mismatched example, it is hard to be sure exactly what you meant. So perhaps your requirements statement is:

"the first element in the body with a href attribute"

If that is the case, then I would suggest the XPath:

```
($input//*[@href][ancestor::body])[1]
```

Note that the sequence constructor, i.e. the '(' and ')' flattens the descendant sequence(s) to allow you to address each selected descendant in a manner similar to an array.