# Differences between // and /descendant in XPath selecting multiple children

Tags: xpath, parent-child

I can't clearly understand the differences between using `//element` and `/descendant::element` when selecting multiple children of a base element in XPath.

Given this HTML snippet

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="popupContent">
  <table>
    <tr class="aclass"><td> Hello </td> <td> <input type="text" value="FIRST" /> </td></tr>
    <tr class="aclass"><td> Goodbye </td> <td> <input type="text" value="SECOND" /> </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to select each `input` based on its positioning in the table.
`//div[@class='popupContent']//input[1]`  this selects the first input
`//div[@class='popupContent']//input[2]`  this gives **error**
`//div[@class='popupContent']/descendant::input[1]` this again selects the first input
`//div[@class='popupContent']/descendant::input[2]` this select the second input

Using `/descendant::input` does what I need: grab all inputs and let me select by position.
How does `//` differ? Why does it return only the first element and not the ones after?

I'm aware of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537771/whats-the-difference-between-node-and-descendantnode-in-xpath) but the answer basically says they're aliases and point to the documentation, which I cannot understand and lacks a concrete example. Difference with that question is that my need is to select multiple children elements, and `//` doesn't allow it.

Comment: first expression `//div[@class='popupContent']//input[1]` returns both inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between //node and /descendant::node in xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537771/whats-the-difference-between-node-and-descendantnode-in-xpath)

Comment: @RobertColumbia as I mentioned in the question itself, I'm asking for a different clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between `//X` and `/descendant::X` is when X contains a positional predicate, for example `//x[1]` vs `/descendant::x[1]`. In this situation `//x[1]` selects every `x` element that is the first `x` child of its parent element, whereas `/descendant::x[1]` selects the first descendant x overall. You can work this out by remembering that `//x[1]` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::x[1]`

Answer (score 15):

According to [XPath 1.0, §2.5 Abbreviated Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`

So `div[@class='popupContent']//input[1]` (same as `div[@class='popupContent']/descendant-or-self::node()/child::input[1]`) will:

1. go to all descendants (children, children of children and so on) of the `div`s with that "popupContent" class,
2. then look for `<input>` children
3. and finally select the first child of its parent (`[1]` predicate)

`div[@class='popupContent']//input[2]` is very similar except the last thing is to select the 2nd child.
And none of the `<input>`s are 2nd child of their parent.

`div[@class='popupContent']/descendant::input[2]` on the other hand will:

1. go to all descendants of the `div`s with that class,
2. selecting only `<input>` elements, and build a *node-set* out of them
3. finally select the 2nd element in that node-set, in document order

You can read about predicates and axes in [§2.4 Predicates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates). Relevant pieces:

> (...) the ancestor, ancestor-or-self, preceding, and preceding-sibling axes are reverse axes; **all other axes are forward axes**.

[Thus `descendant` is a forward axis.]

> The **proximity position of a member of a node-set** with respect to an axis is defined to be the **position of the node in the node-set ordered in document order if the axis is a forward axis** (...). The first position is 1.
>
> A predicate filters a node-set with respect to an axis to produce a new node-set. For each node in the node-set to be filtered, the `PredicateExpr` is evaluated with that node as the context node, with the number of nodes in the node-set as the context size, and **with the proximity position of the node in the node-set with respect to the axis as the context position**;