# Too many results when finding within element with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I did the following search

```
parts.get(i).findElements(By.xpath("//li[starts-with(@class, '_lessons--row-')]"))
```

and it returned dozens of results, while I see in Developer Tools, that there are no more than 3 of them.

`parts.get(i)` returns single [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

Looks like it searches not children of a given element, but over entire page. Can double slash cause this? What double slash means in XPath?

Comment: `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev for more info.

Comment: "descendant or self" sounds contradicting with what other people saying (from root)?

Comment: Take a look at the link to the spec above. Scroll past the examples in the beginning of that section and read the last few paragraphs. It explains both `//` and `.` and how they work together.

Comment: This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33918010/317052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath is faulty here.

```
"//li[starts-with(@class, '_lessons--row-')]"
```

`//` searches from root level, to search from node preappend `.`:

```
".//li[starts-with(@class, '_lessons--row-')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your xpath with .// , normally you should start xpath with "." to stop finding elements from root.

```
.//li[starts-with(@class, '_lessons--row-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`//` match relative data. which starts at the document root. In your case you are trying to locate using

```
//li[starts-with(@class, '_lessons--row-')]
```

So it will return all the match in your html. If you want to locate some specific portion of element with `class` have start text`_lessons--row-` . You have to make your `xpath` more specific.

e.g

```
 //div[@id='someid']//li[starts-with(@class, '_lessons--row-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case, but `.` before `//` didn't help me. Just added `findElements(By.xpath("your_xpath")).stream().filter(WebElement::isDisplayed).toList()` as a workaround.