# descendants:: vs // in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

What is the difference between the following two XPath expressions?

```
//Title
descendant::Title
```

Are they both the exact same, or is there any difference in how they operate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difference:

- `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, and the `descendant-or-self::` axis includes the context item.
- The `descendant::` axis does not include the context item.

So for this XML, assuming the default context item<sup>1</sup> is the root element (the outer `Title` element),

```
<Title id="t1">
  <Title id="t2"/>
</Title>
```

- `//Title` selects both `Title` elements (`id="t1"` and `id="t2"`)
- `descendant::Title` selects only the inner `Title` element (`id="t2"`)

Unasked but noteworthy:

- `/descendant::Title` selects both `Title` elements (`id="t1"` and `id="t2"`)

The difference between `/descendant::Title` and `//Title` manifests only if `Title` were to have a positional predicate.  See [Differences between // and /descendant in XPath selecting multiple children](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33918010/290085) for further details.

---

<sup>1</sup> ***Default context item note***

Thanks to Michael Kay for pointing out the importance of explicitly stating the context item here.  Elaborating...

Some XPath tools (e.g: [oXygen XML](https://www.oxygenxml.com/)) default the context item to the *root element* (the outer `Title`, here); other XPath tools (e.g: [XPather.com](http://xpather.com/)) default the context item to the *root node*.  If the context item is the root node, `descendant::Title` also will select both `Title` elements.

**See also**

- [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1022345/290085)
- [What is the difference between root node, root element and document element in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025654/290085)

Comment: Surely this is only true if the context item is the outer `Title` element? If the context item is the document node, `descendant::X` and `//X` have exactly the same effect - though as you say, positional predicates behave differently.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Correct, answer updated to call out the importance of the default context item.  Thank you!